# Grok can't create optional fields

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to parse logs in logstash with use of grok.
In error log there are two more optional fields like requestUrl and requestMethod.
but when i use grok for parsing logs to logstash.these from the error log grok can't create these two fields.

**mypipeline.conf** :

```
input {
 beats {
    type=>"mytest"
    port => 5044
     
  }
} 
filter{
    if [fields][log_type] == "gbase"
    {
       if [level] in [ "Error", "Fatal" ] 
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{INT:processId} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{URI:requestUrl} %{USER:requestMethod} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
            overwrite => [ "message" ]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4} ",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{level}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{logger}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{clientIp}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{processId}",""]}
        }
        else
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{INT:processId} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
            overwrite => [ "message" ]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4} ",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{level}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{logger}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{clientIp}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{processId}",""]}
        }
        
    }
    if [fields][log_type] == "finance" 
    {
       if [level] in [ "Error", "Fatal" ] 
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:receivedAt} \[%{INT:processId}]\ %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{URI:requestUrl} %{WORD:requestMethod} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
            overwrite => [ "message" ]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4} ",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{level}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{logger}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{clientIp}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{processId}",""]}
        }
        else
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:receivedAt} \[%{INT:processId}]\ %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
        overwrite => [ "message" ]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4} ",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{level}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{logger}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{clientIp}",""]}
                mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{processId}",""]}
        }
        
    
    }
   date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
        #match => [ "time" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        target=> "@timestamp"
    }
}
output {
 
    if [fields][log_type] == "finance"
    {
        elasticsearch 
        {
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"] 
            index => "finance-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => "something"
            password => "something"     
        }
    } 
    if [fields][log_type] == "gbase"
    {
        elasticsearch 
        {
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"] 
            index => "gbase-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => "something"
            password => "something" 
        }
    }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log 
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\Git\gbase.API\API\Logs\*.log
  tags: ["gbaseapi"]
  fields: 
    log_type: gbase   
  multiline.pattern:  ^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
  multiline.max_lines : 1000

- type: log 
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\Git\finance.api\FinanceAPI\logs\*.log
  tags: ["financeapi"]
  fields: 
    log_type: finance
  multiline.pattern:  ^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after    
  multiline.max_lines : 1000
```

**my log sample :**

```
2020-10-10 21:14:59.8746 22152 WARN Validation bhavin 192.168.43.244 Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data, this mode should only be enabled during development. 
2020-10-10 21:15:35.2745 22152 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread bhavin 192.168.43.244 Batch acquisition of 0 triggers 
2020-10-10 21:15:35.2783 22152 ERROR DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware bhavin 192.168.43.244 http://bhavin/Leads/New POST An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**json document**

```
{
         "input" => {
        "type" => "log"
    },
     "processId" => "34076",
           "log" => {
          "file" => {
            "path" => "D:\\Git\\gbase.API\\API\\Logs\\log-2020-10-10.log"
        },
         "flags" => [
            [0] "multiline"
        ],
        "offset" => 43633
    },
      "clientIp" => "192.168.43.244",
        "fields" => {
        "log_type" => "gbase"
    },
     "timestamp" => "2020-10-10 21:29:00.1492",
           "ecs" => {
        "version" => "1.5.0"
    },
          "user" => "bhavin",
         "agent" => {
                "name" => "Bhavin",
            "hostname" => "Bhavin",
                "type" => "filebeat",
             "version" => "7.9.2",
                  "id" => "b5decaac-61a3-4dbc-860b-4423a0379391",
        "ephemeral_id" => "208d7c9d-bdcd-45e9-8f82-ccdb08292203"
    },
         "level" => "ERROR",
       "message" => "http://bhavin/Leads/New POST An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.GurukulERP.Logic.InvalidDataException: Provide a valid PhoneNumber.\n   at GurukulERP.API.Controllers.CRM.LeadsController.New(AdmissionLead model) in D:\\Git\\gbase.API\\API\\Controllers\\CRM\\LeadsController.cs:line 515\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics..Invoke(HttpContext context)    at GurukulERP.API.Controllers.CRM.LeadsController.New(AdmissionLead model) in D:\\Git\\gbase.API\\API\\Controllers\\CRM\\LeadsController.cs:line 515\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics..Invoke(HttpContext context)",
          "host" => {
                "name" => "Bhavin",
            "hostname" => "Bhavin",
        "architecture" => "x86_64",
                 "mac" => [
            [0] "04:92:26:4a:aa:7b",
            [1] "52:3e:aa:6a:59:4c",
            [2] "50:3e:aa:6a:59:4c",
            [3] "00:ff:73:c0:8e:ca",
            [4] "50:3e:aa:6a:59:4c"
        ],
                  "id" => "2540a614-ed14-468c-82b6-3c2f1de5b687",
                  "ip" => [
            [ 0] "fe80::8511:1aea:78ea:8722",
            [ 1] "169.254.135.34",
            [ 2] "fe80::a1dc:1a7d:8369:4ee5",
            [ 3] "169.254.78.229",
            [ 4] "fe80::c9b5:254f:10b3:191d",
            [ 5] "169.254.25.29",
            [ 6] "fe80::ac32:76b1:509a:bc5e",
            [ 7] "169.254.188.94",
            [ 8] "2405:204:808b:8dbb:d456:182e:dd87:ca6",
            [ 9] "2405:204:808b:8dbb:3132:508b:53c1:132e",
            [10] "fe80::d456:182e:dd87:ca6",
            [11] "192.168.43.244"
        ],
                  "os" => {
                "name" => "Windows 10 Enterprise",
            "platform" => "windows",
              "kernel" => "10.0.18362.1082 (WinBuild.160101.0800)",
             "version" => "10.0",
              "family" => "windows",
               "build" => "18362.1082"
        }
    },
      "@version" => "1",
          "type" => "mytest",
    "@timestamp" => 2020-10-10T15:59:02.229Z,
          "tags" => [
        [0] "gbaseapi",
        [1] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
        [2] "_dateparsefailure"
    ],
        "logger" => "DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware"
}
```

here is image of kibana view :

[image: Untitled.png]

you can see the other fields are created but these two are not create

Comment: Can you update your question with your full logstash pipeline? Also, are you using filebeat, right? Share your filebeat config also and the json output of your a document, to show which fields are available.

Comment: I updated my question you can see all files

Comment: Your `grok` to create the fields `requestUrl` and `requestMethod` needs that your `if` condition returns `true`, but your conditional uses the field `level`, which does not exists in your document when it enters your pipeline, so it will never be true. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: so you have any solution of this?. because i don't know the other option to check this condtion.

Comment: You do not need to check on anything, just parse the messages, check my answer to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `level` does not exist in your document when it enters your pipeline, so the conditional you are using in your grok will never match to `true`.

Looking at your example messages, they have basically the same structure, they only start to be different after the ip address, you can use just one `grok` to parse all those messages and then have another grok that will only be applied if the overwritten `message` field starts with an URI.

The following filter will parse all of your example messages.

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{INT:processId} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
        overwrite => "message"
    }

    if [message] =~ "^http:" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{URI:requestUrl} %{USER:requestMethod} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            overwrite => "message"
        }
    }
}
```

The first `grok` will parse the messages and overwrite the `message` field with everything the comes after the ip address. So, in the case of the message that you want to extract the `requestUrl` and `requestMethod`, you will have the message field with the following value.

```
http://bhavin/Leads/New POST An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The `if [message] =~ "^http:"` part will check if the `message` field starts with `http:`, and if `true` it will parse this message, which will then create the fields `requestUrl` and `requestMethod` and a new overwritten `message` field.

Also, your `gsub` filters makes no sense, you can remove it.

You can apply the same process to your `finance` log type, the only difference seems to be that the `processId` appears between square brackets and you are using another field for the timestamp.

Comment: I did it and it's working perfectly. Thank you so much ! it's great help